# If $X^Y = Y^X$, prove that $X = Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $X$ and $Y$ are two sets. $X^Y$ denotes the set of all functions from $Y$ to $X$. Similarly, $Y^X$ denotes the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$. If $X^Y = Y^X$, prove that $X = Y$.

I tried to show this by way of contradiction, but my argument seems to be lacking rigor. To begin, assume that $X\neq Y$. Then there exists $y\in Y$ such that $y \notin X$. If we think about $X^Y$, then this set contains functions $f:Y\to X$, which assign a unique image $f(y)$ to $y\in Y$. As $y\notin X$, we can obviously *not find* such functions in $Y^X$. So $X^Y \neq Y^X$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $X=Y$.

Are there better ways of proving this? Is my argument complete? How can I make it more rigorous?

Comment: Just think about constant functions.

Comment: Yeah, so if $y\in Y$ and $y\notin X$, I can construct a constant function $g:X\to Y$ such that $g(x) = y$ for all $x$. Since $y\notin X$, $g \notin X^Y$. Does this work?

Comment: Yes. You can also prove it directly this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function maps every element in the domain to some element in the co-domain.

So, pick your favorite $y \in Y$. Let $f:X\to Y$ be $f(x) = y$. But that means $f: Y \to X$ defined as $f(x) = y$ also exists. Since this is the same $f$, the domains must be the same, so $X = Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X = Y = \emptyset$ then this is trivial. Otherwise, let $f\in X^Y = Y^X$ and let $x \in X$. Then $f(y) = x$ for some $y \in Y$, but also $f(y) = f(x_{1})$ for some $x_{1} \in X$ so that $x\in Y$. The other way is proven similarly.